# Panoramic stills with 6 cubemapped images

Tags: photography

Are there any recommended websites for hosting panoramic 3D renders, where the panorama is distributed across 6 faces of a cube? I have seen some that support equirectangular images, but I don't think they look as good. If the service is offered for free, that is a bonus. Thanks!